# How to make your own shapefile in a similar manner to GADMTools in R

Tags: r, maps, shapefile

I have used GADMTools for creating shapefiles in the past. However, this package has not been updated, so it no longer works with the latest version of R. Currently, I need to make some changes to my maps, and I'm looking for something similar to solve my problem. My old code is:

```
joinmap <- gadm_sp_loadCountries(c("RUS","LTU","LVA","EST","FIN", "POL","BLR"),  basefile = "./")
studyarea <- gadm_crop(joinmap, xmin=19, ymin=50, xmax=25, ymax=56)
gadm_exportToShapefile(studyarea, "path for shapefile")
```

I need to join some countries, cut the desired territory, and save it as a shapefile so that I can work further with ArcGIS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use `sf::st_write(..., driver="ESRI Shapefile")`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I would also like to know how to combine different countries and then crop territory based on latitude and longitude ranges.

Comment: well, at the possibility of sounding redundant, there are `sf::st_crop()` & `sf::st_combine`. maybe check out the documentation concerning `sf`. i find it easier/more intuitive to work with than `sp`.